# How to adjust the order of data in Dataset by Date asc? , C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, dataset

I am assigning data to a `Dataset` manually from the data of another `Dataset`, in which two conditions are met one when there is data from another `Dataset` where the `date` field matches the rows with this data, otherwise I add them as a new row. This is perfect.

The problem is that when you finish assigning the data to the `Dataset`, the data that shows first are the ones that are updated with the first condition.

> I need the data to be sorted by Date either `dd\MM\yyyy` or `yyyy/MM/dd` without taking into account the hours, and regardless of whether it was updated or added, but to order it by `Date` of `ASC` mode.

```
//foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x=>x.Field<DateTime>("date").Date).ToList())
{
    var row=dataset_manually.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(x=> x.Field<DateTime>("date").Date == ((DateTime)dr["date"]).Date).FirstOrDefault();

    if (row!=null)
    {
         //Update the data
         row["entryToTurn"]=(DateTime)dr["entryToTurn"];
         row["departureToTurn"]=(DateTime)dr["departureToTurn"];
         row["turn"]=dr["turn"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
         //Add new rows
         var row2= dataset_manually.Tables[0].NewRow();
         row2["entryToTurn"] = dr["entryToTurn"];
         row2["departureToTurn"] = dr["departureToTurn"];
         row2["turn"] = dr["turn"].ToString();
         dataset_manually.Tables[0].Rows.Add(fila2);
    }
}
```

> For some reason the `OrderBy` in the `foreach` does not work. adds the data but does not order it. `foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x=>x.Field<DateTime>("date").Date).ToList())`

I tried this but it did not work:

```
dataset_manually.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "date asc";
```

[image]

And I can not do it like this:

```
datagridview1.Sort(datagridview1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

Because this only shows the data ordered in the `DataGridView` but when using the `Dataset` in another side the data is not sorted and the positions of the values in the grid are not the same things in the `Dataset`.

**Desired output:**

[image]

Note: The data is NOT assigned by the `index`, it must be assigned where the `date` field matches

**Environment:** Visual Studio 2010 (WindowsForms C#) & .NET NetFramework 4

Comment: Have you specified your Date column to be of type `DateTime` ?

Comment: @Marco Yeah the column is of type `Datetime`

Comment: @DragandDrop it does not work

Comment: Making copies of rows just to put them in any sort of order is inefficient and makes this sound like an XY problem

Comment: @Plutonix Please I need to solve the problem, in this case the ds contains 7 rows and the manual dataset contains 3 rows, therefore the manual dataset will update the data of these 3 rows and add the 4 missing rows

Comment: @Marco Please help me

Comment: We have no idea what the real problem is, just that this solution you are trying to implement doesnt work.  You certainly dont need 2 datasets to hold essentially the same table.  Why are the 2 new rows only added to the "manually" DataSet? Is it just for purposes of this sort?

Comment: @Plutonix I'm not an expert but I really need help. The purpose of this is to present the daily worked hours of the employees, the data will always bring the data of the employee's schedule, while the manual dataset may contain some hours and on certain days be blank so I must complete the data of the manual dataset with the data contained in the ds

Comment: Deleting a downvoted post means the DVs will count against you forever,  The real solution is to clarify the problem and make the post clearer.  Whining about DVs only brings more.  IF the data is an amalgam of 2 tables it seems like either a bad DB design or you could use a SQL JOIN to glue them together

Comment: @Plutonix I have tried to clarify the purpose for which I am doing this process, but it is difficult to explain clearly and that they can understand me since I am not an expert in programming. That is why I have many deficiencies in my code. In the end, the only thing I want is to order the data Departure by date

Comment: @Plutonix I can not use a join to join, because this data I get from a stored procedure that returns multiple datatables, used both for different cases, I can not really unite the data in that way

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you first sort your data set and then you add new rows to it (so after everything)

Solution for this is slow if you have a lot of rows inside data set so I AM RECOMMENDING TO DO NOT DO THIS BUT SORT DATA AFTER LOADING IT INTO CODE.

Solution to this problem could be:

- Load Data from DB into dataGridView
- Get dataSource from dataGridView as DataTable
- Add new data to DataTable
- Sort DataTable
- Save sorted data

Sorting could be done with:

```
DataView dv = data.DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "PrimaryColumn asc" //desc for descending
data = dv.ToTable();
```

Comment: And what can I do if I have this condition:  `DataView dv = ds.Tables["Table1","Table2"].DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "PrimaryColumn asc"`  the dataset contains two tables, how can I assign the two tables again **ds = dv.ToTable();** without losing the second one?

Comment: `ds` is dataSource?

Comment: @Aleska Ristic How can I create a view of a dataset that contains two tables, sort table 1 and reassign that view to the dataset without losing the data in the second table

Comment: You said you create custom data set from your main one and you change data in the custom one. What dataset is assigned to datagridview?

Comment: @Aleska Ristic The custom data set is `dataset_manually` and it contains 2 tables, of which in this procedure I am using `table0` and in another procedure I use table1, to `datagridview.DataSource` I am assigning it `dataset_manually.Tables [0]`

Comment: So hard to understand what you are doing. It would be good if you share whole code.

If you cannot share it here use pastebin.com

Comment: There is no way to explain my process anymore :( but it is possible to do this: _How can I create a view of a dataset that contains two tables, sort table 1 and reassign that view to the dataset without losing the data in the second table_  if that is possible I can solve my problem

Comment: In the SO Community in Spanish there are less members and they have not been able to help me completely. [Here is the complete detail of the problem](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/138871/69447). You can make the page in English and understand the process in more detail.